# Problema con DatePicker en Android

Tags: android, android-studio

La intención es que al hacer click en un EditText se habra el datepicker.

Adjunto pantallazo donde se ve el error + codigo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.icu.util.Calendar;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText fechas;
int dia, mes, year, uno, dos, tres;

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    fechas = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.fechas);




    fechas.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

            dia = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            mes = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    DatePickerDialog d = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            fechas.setText(dayOfMonth+"/"+(monthOfYear+1)+"/"+year);
        }
    }
    ,dia,mes,year);
            d.show();


        }
    });



}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando inicializas el `DatePickerDialog`, el primer parametro debe de ser un `Context` y el estas pasando la instancia de la interfaz `View.OnClickListener`:

```
fechas.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

            dia = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            mes = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);

// this no se refiere al contexto, sino a la instancia actual de la interfaz
    DatePickerDialog d = new DatePickerDialog(this, //...
```

Tienes que enviarle la instancia del contexto o del activity asi:

```
 DatePickerDialog d = new DatePickerDialog(NombreActividadActual.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            fechas.setText(dayOfMonth+"/"+(monthOfYear+1)+"/"+year);
        }
    }
    ,dia,mes,year);
```

Donde `NombreActividadActual` es el nombre del activity donde estas creando el `DatePickerDialog`.